# how to login to graphql page(localhost:8000/graphql) with django

Tags: python, django, graphql

I want to use @login_required function like below code.
and I want to check the query correctly works.

```
import graphene 
from graphql_jwt.decorators import login_required


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @login_required
    def resolve_me(self, info):
        user=info.context.user
        return types.UserProfileResponse(user=user)
```

i put the code into graphql(localhost:8000/graphql)

query{me{user{id}}}}

the message is you do not have permission to perform this action

I think maybe I have to give token to graphql. but i don't know how to give token.
could you teach me?

Answer (score 1):

`@login_required` is a [decorator for a view function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) (which takes a `request` as its first parameter), you cannot use it on your method.

You either have to do the check manually (`if user.is_authenticated` ...) or move this to the view. Latter is the better option, because a view can decide how to respond in this case, whereas your method can't.